# Laravel send email using mail::to without viewing other recipients

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of recipients `$this->recipients` and I want to send an email to all recipients without showing each other emails.
Currently, it shows all the recipients in an email.
[image]

```
 if (count($this->recipients) > 1) {
                Mail::bcc($this->recipients)
                    ->send(new EmailNotificationMailable($this->notificationRequest));
            } else {
                Mail::to($this->recipients)
                    ->send(new EmailNotificationMailable($this->notificationRequest));
            }
```

I tried this code but when I send with `Mail::bcc` the `To` of email is empty.
Please give the working solution for this. I don't want to loop recipients array

Comment: Just set the recipients one at a time and send one mail for each recipient. By default emails are send via a queue so this should be quick. No need to overthink this

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the recipients collection:

```
if(count($this->recipients) > 1)
{
 $this->recipients->each(function($recipient)
 {
    Mail::to(recipient)->bcc($this->recipients)->send(new EmailNotificationMailable($this->notificationRequest));
 }
}else{
    Mail::to($this->recipients)->send(new EmailNotificationMailable($this->notificationRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```php
Mail::to(array_pop($this->recipients))->bcc($this->recipients)
```

This will set the last entry in the `recipients` array as the mail receiver and every other addresses will be included via BCC.

Comment: I want to send emails individually to all recipients.

Comment: Every one in the recipients list will receive the mail, and as each one of them are included via `bcc` none will be able to see other recipients address.

Comment: But what will be the `To` in the email?
I guess it will be the last recipients in the array for all?
@Pusparaj

Comment: yes the email's primary recipient will be the last entry in the array but as you are sending with `bcc` header, everyone will felt like its custom delivered to their address.